# Passing state to child components as properties

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently learning React router v1.0 and I'm having a confusion with passing state to child components as properties.

App.js

```
  getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    status: 'disconnected',
    title: ''
  },
  ...
  ,
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} status={this.state.status}/>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children,{title:this.state.title,status:this.state.status})}
      </div>
    );
```

Client.js

```
var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Audience} />
    <Route path ="speaker" component={Speaker} />
  </Route>
</Router>
);
```

Audience.js

```
render: function(){
  return(
  <div>
    <h1>Audience</h1>
    {this.props.title || "Welcome Audience"}
    </div>
 );
}
```

Speaker.js

```
render: function(){
    return(
    <div>
     <h1>Speaker:</h1>
     {this.props.status || "Welcome Speaker!"}
    </div>
  );
  }
```

Instead of doing this:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children,{title:this.state.title,status:this.state.status})}
```

Is there something similar like this for React.cloneElement using the https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html operator:

```
<RouteHandler {...this.state}/>
```

**TLDR;** Basically I would like to pass the entire state to my Route Components instead of individually defining them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Object.assign({}, this.state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple answer would be just no.

---

As you can see in [this comment](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1531#issuecomment-146514399) - there are some ways to achieve this behaviour (the way you're doing is one of them), and maybe you've seen all of them already, but I wouldn't suggest you to use any of them, unless really necessary.

You should really check these discussions about it in the following threads:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1857

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1531

> @ryanflorence [Co-author of React-router]
>
> You should think of your route components as entry points into the app
>   that don't know or care about the parent, and the parent shouldn't
>   know/care about the children.

**Usually the best way to handle these cases would be using something like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) - where the whole state of your app is stored in an object tree and it can be easily shared across your route components.**